# iPython Notebook output latex or mathjax

Tags: python, latex, ipython, mathjax

How do you get iPython to output results using latex?

For example, like on this page: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ipython/ipython/master/examples/notebooks/SymPy%20Examples.ipynb

If I execute the code:

```
Rational(3,2)*pi + exp(I*x) / (x**2 + y)
```

I get output:

```
Out[13]: 3*pi/2 + exp(I*x)/(x**2 + y)
```

I want to see output in latex as shown in the link above.

Comment: Did you run all the imports include at that link?

Comment: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#module-sympy.printing.latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As done in the link you posted and mentioned by @tcaswell you need to "activate" the latex printing using

```py
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
```

the use_latex=True statement is required with sympy 0.7.2 but not with 0.7.3.

Comment: The issue in my case was i had an older version of sympy, but your answer led me to checking what version i had and updating my sympy and it now works.

Answer (score 7):

An updated answer for those googlers:

```
from IPython.display import Math
Math('3 \cdot \\frac{\pi}{2} + e^{\\frac{I*x}{x^2 + y}}')
```

A bit more clumsy than SymPy, but doesn't need an extra package.